# Partially hidden content on scrollable divs

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

I've been searching for similar questions to these, but I couldn't find one, so I'm exposing my problem, hoping you could tell me what am I doing wrong and how to correct it.
I'm trying the accomplish the following scenario: two divs, side by side, using 100% of height and width, in which the left one can be scrollable. The right one has a few divs on top of each other, and the last one should have its contents scrollable too.
A picture can better describe the scenario:

[image: OP's Layout]

The blue divs are the ones that can be scrollable, but the height of red ones is unknown.
I was able to partially accomplish this, but the problem is that the content of the last div is pulled down from the view in the same proportion as the height sum of the red divs, so when the user scrolls that blue div he won't be able to view the full content of it.
What can I do to solve this?
I also got a fiddle where this behavior can be reproduced: http://jsfiddle.net/d3dNG/3/
Thanks for any feedback on this.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="left">
        Left (first)<br />
        [...]Left<br />
        Left (last)<br />
</div>
<div id="right">
    <div id="header1">Header 1</div>
    <div id="header1">Header 2</div>
    <div id="header1">Header 3</div>
    <div id="rightContent">
        Right (first)<br />
        Right<br />
        [...]
        Right (last)<br />
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: pink;
}

#left {
float: left;
width: 100px;
height: 100%;
overflow-y: auto;
background: gold;
}

#right {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#rightContent {
height: 100%;
overflow-y: auto;
background: lime;
}
```

Comment: Are you open to a jQuery solution?

Comment: I was hoping for a CSS only solution, but obviously I'm open to any solution for this particular problem. Thanks (and for the edit as well)

Comment: If you will not know the height of your header section then you, sadly, will have to resort to a script solution.

Comment: I forgot to mention, not problem for the edit!

Comment: @JoshPowell I have the same issue, except I do know the height of my header section. With that in mind, is there a pure css solution for this issue?

Comment: @elad.chen there is a pure css solution that has IE9<= support. You can use css `calc()` to determine the height, only problem is `calc()` has poor browser support on some phones.

Comment: @elad.chen here is a fiddle using css `calc()`. http://jsfiddle.net/ThtUH/ and browser support info, http://caniuse.com/calc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you will not know what the size of `#header1` you can go about this by using javascript or jQuery.

(**Make sure to only use `ids` once on your page since they are unique, `#header1` is used 3 times**)

The html I changed:

```
<div class="headParent">
     <div class="header1">Header 1</div>
     <div class="header1">Header 2</div>
     <div class="header1">Header 3</div>
</div>
```

The little jQuery I wrote:

```
function rightSize() {
    var hH = $('.headParent').height(), // grabs the `#header1`'s parents height
        mH = $('#rightContent').height() - hH; // minus the height from the `#rightContent`

    $('#rightContent').css({height: mH});
}

rightSize();
```

Finally, a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/d3dNG/9/)

[Even once there is more](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/d3dNG/10/) of the `.header1` the `#rightContent` will still adapt correctly to fit the content.

Comment: Thanks. The #header1 was a typo, it was supposed to be header1, header2..., to indicate different content type from div to div.
The only thing missing is a 'on resize' event, since the height of #rightContent needs to be recalculated. I tried the $(window).resize() event, but it didn't produce any results, probably an error on my part.

Comment: Ahh well I'm glad it was a typo, lol. Give me a second and I'll show you how to do on resize.

Comment: @NunoM The `.on('resize')` is a lot more tricky then I was expecting. Here is a, http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/d3dNG/17/, fiddle to start you off. Current problems, does not work for on load and the resizing is very weird.

Comment: The jQuery solution worked fine on my real problem, except on one scenario, the load event. I'm developing a AngularJS app and the templates where I need this solution are only loaded when the user visits them. Since there's no page reload on my app, the load event is never triggered, although the resize event is. I'm trying to get a workaround for this case, but will accept this answer. Thanks once again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="left">
        Left (first)<br />
        [...]Left<br />
        Left (last)<br />
</div>
<div id="rightOne">
    <div id="header1">Header 1</div>
    <div id="header1">Header 2</div>
    <div id="header1">Header 3</div>
</div>
<div id="rightTwo">
    <div id="rightContent">
        Right (first)<br />
        Right<br />
        [...]
        Right (last)<br />
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#rightOne {
    height: 16%;
    width: 100%;
}

#rightTwo {
    height: 84%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d3dNG/4/

Comment: The height of the red divs needs to be unknown, and it not be based on percentage, but rather on their contents.

Comment: Then there is no "css only" solution, check the answer of @Josh Powell, that should work.